# Listview with onTouchListener

Tags: android, listview, ontouchlistener

I have a listView. In that listView i have implemented onTouchListener. Every things work fine, but when list  is Scrolling , on tapping on the list , the list should stop(like normal android listView).No action can be done while scrolling like stopping the scroll.This happen because of the onTouchListener. I am returning **false** from onTouchListener. I don't know why this behavior happens?Can any one help.

Comment: why are you implementing onTouchListener? What's the goal?

Comment: i wanted to implement 2 finger swipe in it.

Comment: what you mean by "2 finger swipe" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try returning `super.onTouchListener`, or `true`, when you don't want to consume the event (i'm thinking you implemented gestures). returning false means you're discarding the TouchEvent, and you don't want to do that if you want to stop the scroll.